# gcloud compute global address with node.js package

Tags: node.js, ip-address, gcloud, gcloud-node

I'm currently using [google cloud's node.js google compute package](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.11.x/module-@google-cloud_compute) to [create an address](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.11.x/Address).

However, it doesn't seem like there's any way to create global (not regional) addresses, as the `node.js` package requires a `region`. [Through gcloud's REST api, it seems like there's a way to create global addresses.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address)

> For global static IPv6 addresses, make a request to:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT_ID]/global/addresses
>   Your request body should contain the following:
>
> {   "name": "[ADDRESS_NAME]",   "ipVersion": "IPV6" }

Does anybody know if there's a way to make global addresses using the package?

Answer (score 1):

All of the REST clients expose a `request` function you can call

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();

const request = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: '/global/addresses',
  json: {name: 'my-address'}
};

compute.request(request, (err, resp) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }

  compute
    .operation(resp.name)
    .on('error', err => console.error(err))
    .on('complete', response => {
      // good to go!
    });
});
```